# Can't define a foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

In MySQL I've two tables:

```
Monitors:
    Id: INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT
    GroupId: INT NULL
    ....

MonitorGroups:
    Id: INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT
    Name: VARCHAR(50)
```

I need to define this constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Monitors ADD CONSTRAINT monitor_group_fk FOREIGN KEY (GroupId) REFERENCES MonitorGroups (Id);
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zm`.`#sql-475_1c237`, CONSTRAINT `monitor_group_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`GroupId`) REFERENCES `MonitorGroups` (`Id`))
```

At the moment there's no record in MonitorGroups table and GroupId of rows of table Monitors are not set. I need it to be legal. In another words, I need MySQL to keep track of the field GroupId of table Monitor only if it's set. I would like to define the constraint as:

```
ALTER TABLE Monitors ADD CONSTRAINT monitor_group_fk FOREIGN KEY (GroupId) REFERENCES MonitorGroups (Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

so that if a group id (Id field) changed in table MonitorGroups, MySQL change it automatically in table Monitors and if a group was deleted from table MonitorGroups, MySQL automatically set GroupId of corresponding rows in table Monitors to null.
What's wrong and how to reach this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is da ROW in the table Monitors, which has a value in the column "GroupId" for which the foreign key constraint fails (=it does not exist in the table MonitorGroups).
Check if there is a GroupId whithout a corresponding Id-Value in table Groups.

Comment: yes, you're right. as i said, i need to validate existence of rows in table Monitors with GroupId NULL. I know that some database managers support nullable foreign keys, but I'm not sure whether MySQL does it too and how it does.

Comment: NULL is not the problem here?

Comment: hmm, see, I need no Id of table MonitorGroups be zero or null. I may allow a row in table Monitors have GroupId of zero, but if assigned another value, it should assign from table MonitorGroups. Is it possible?

Comment: I added a row in table Groups with Id zero and this resolved the problem. But I need to know how can I avoid this.

Comment: don't know what you're doing. "0" is a valid value with has to be existent on "MonitorGroups"-Table. NULL just says: no foreign key

Comment: I thought it was clear enough. I need not to add any row to MonitorGroups table at first and define the foreign key in such a situation. Certainly all GroupId's in Monitors table should set to NULL (identical to 0 for me). If a GroupId then will have to set to a value other than 0, it should be picked from MonitorGroup table's Id. That's if a GroupId has no value, it's ok. But if it has a value other than 0, it should exist in MonitorGroups table. But I couldn't define such a foreign key.

Comment: Besides, I prefer no Id of a row in MonitorGroups table be set to 0. This is what I want.

Comment: *" should set to NULL (identical to 0 for me)"* `0` is not identical to `NULL` in SQL.

Comment: If you really need to use 0 instead of null you need to add a 0 monitor group. Beside you can't use the action defined on the foreign key, you need to update any monitors for the monitor group before you delete it.

Comment: so i prefer not to use the foreign key and do synchronizations manually.